# Framer Motion ReOrder behaviour not reordering as expected

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, framer-motion, reorderlist, reorderable-list

I am currently trying to implemented a draggable re-orderable list with Framer Motion. I am trying to reproduce the following behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-5-drag-to-reorder-lists-uonye?from-embed=&file=/src/Icon.tsx:49-54

I have an `ingredientList` that contains the `create_index` of the each of the ingredients created in my Formik form, which are accessible as `values.ingredients`.

The main issue I am having is that the list items are not behaving smoothly as they do in the code example and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

This is my parent component in which I set the ingredientList

```
const IngredientTab = ({values}: any) => {
  const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState(values.ingredients.map((ingredient) => ingredient.create_index))

  return (
    <div css={IngredientTabStyles}>
      <FieldArray name="ingredients">
        {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
          <div>
            <Reorder.Group axis="y" values={ingredientList} onReorder={setIngredientList}>
              <AnimatePresence>
                {ingredientList.map((ingredientUniqueValue, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Ingredient 
                      key={index}
                      index={index} 
                      uniqueValue={ingredientUniqueValue} 
                      ingredients={values.ingredients}
                      order={`${ingredientList.indexOf(ingredientUniqueValue) + 1}`}
                    />
                  )
                })}
              </AnimatePresence>
            </Reorder.Group>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="add-ingredients"
              onClick={() => {
                  setIngredientList([...ingredientList, values.ingredients.length])
                  push({ name: '', additional_info: '', quantity: '', unit_id: '', create_index: values.ingredients.length})
                }}
            >
              Add Ingredient
            </button>
          </div>
      )}
      </FieldArray>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IngredientTab

const IngredientTabStyles = css`
  .ingredient-fields {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    background-color: white;
  }
`
```

And this is the Item component:

```
const Ingredient = ({ uniqueValue, ingredients, order, ingredient}: any) => {
  const y = useMotionValue(0);
  const boxShadow = useRaisedShadow(y);

  const ingredientIndex = ingredients.findIndex(ingredient => ingredient.create_index==uniqueValue)

  return (
    <Reorder.Item      
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      key={uniqueValue} 
      value={uniqueValue} 
      style={{boxShadow,y}}
    >
      {ingredient}

      <div className="ingredient-fields" css={IngredientStyles}>
        <div className="order">
          <h6>{order}</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="ingredient-name">
          <Field
            name={`ingredients.${ingredientIndex}.name`}
            type='text'
            placeholder="Ingredient"
          />
          <Field
            name={`ingredients.${ingredientIndex}.additional_info`}
            type='text'
            placeholder="Description"
          />
        </div>
        <Field
          name={`ingredients.${ingredientIndex}.quantity`}
          type='number'
          placeholder="Quantity"
        />
      </div>
    </Reorder.Item>
  )
}

export default Ingredient

const IngredientStyles = css`
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;

  .order {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: ${theme.components.grey};
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
  }

  .ingredient-name {
    display: flex;
  }

  input {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid ${theme.colors.lightGrey};
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
`
```

---

I tried to take screenshots of the behaviour that I currently have. If I try to drag the 'bonjour' to the first position, the 1st item 'hello' does not move downwards. Instead what happens onReorder, what you see in the second picture, the bonjour and hello abruptly switch and it looks as though I am dragging the 'hello' item[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar behavior and found that the key is of utmost importance.

1. Make sure your key is unique
2. Ensure the key is not tied to row index, which changes on a reorder